# TextInputLayout изменение текста Android

Tags: android

Использую TextInputLayout из Material Desing.
Хочу поменять для него цвета для label и для helper error.

```
<style name="Login.TextInputLayout">
     <item name="errorTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

**Сейчас такое поведение.**
По умолчанию в EditText серого цвета.

После нажатия на него, надпись перемещается в label и становится цвета colorPrimary.

Если ошибка, то helper error и label становятся белого цвета (хотя я хочу, чтобы Helper становился белого цвета (так как на темном фоне хорошо виден), а label оставался таким как был (так как там светлый цвет), т.е  colorPrimary, а он меняется вслед за helper.

Как реализовать это?

Пытался принудительно для Label поставить цвет

```
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Но он все равно меняется на белый, если ошибка

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1096037/Изменение-цвета-label-text-в-textfield-material-design/1096104#1096104

Comment: @Andrew данные параметры не влияют ни на TextInputLayout, ни на TextInputEditText